# How to make Buttons/Controls take up max area possible and scale the font to that?

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

So I've been making a Windows Store app. For now, it simply has a bunch of Buttons in a Grid. I want to make it so these Buttons (along with their font size) will scale up/down to accommodate its entire parent. I've tried messing around with http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Scaling-sample-cf072f4f and while it helped me do some scaling, it didn't help me do what I wanted to. I came from an Android background and am used to easily being able to do this. Can I easily accomplish this on C#/XAML applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Viewbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx) class.

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0">
        <Button.Content>
            <Viewbox>
                <TextBlock Text="First button..." />
            </Viewbox>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="1">
        <Button.Content>
            <Viewbox>
                <TextBlock Text="Second button..." />
            </Viewbox>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="2">
        <Button.Content>
            <Viewbox>
                <TextBlock Text="Third button..." />
            </Viewbox>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>        
</Grid>
```

Comment: Does this scale the FontSize as well?

Comment: Awesome. I'll try this out and let you know!